# linq not returning any data

Tags: c#, linq

I have two variables. first variable docList of type www.abc.com.docListResponse. It consists of an array of values with docID[0] = "12345", docID[1] = "34567" docID[2] = "32498"

The second variable is of custom type Documents[] docsColl with values docRefID[0] = "12345", docRefID[1] = "34567", DocRefID[2] = "67890"

The ling operator

```
   var docs =  docsColl.ToList().Where(i => i.docRefID== docList .FirstOrDefault().docID.ToString()).ToArray();
```

I'm expecting it to return two records but its returning 0.

Comment: is it a Linq query ?

Comment: yeah it is a Linq query

Comment: Why do you expect two records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to compose a query using another existing collection, you can generally use the [`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) method to accomplish this, which will return any records that match your specific constraint.

```
var docs = docsColl.Where(d => docList.Any(x => d.docID == x.docRefID));
```

One caveat with this is that if you are using complex types and your initial collection is not in memory (and is in something like a database), LINQ won't know how to properly handle this, so you typically need to either throw a `ToList()` call prior to your `Where()` statement :

```
var docs = docsColl.ToList()
                   .Where(d => docList.Any(x => d.docID == x.docRefID));
```

Or you'll need to ensure that the collection you are using to query through (in this case `docList`) only consists of primitive types like strings :

```
// Get your IDs to check against
var docRefIds = docList.Select(d => d.docRefID).ToArray();
var docs = docsColl.Where(d => docRefIds.Any(r => d.docID == r));
```